# How can I view method documentation while hovering on Code Completion options in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

While typing methods on Android Studio, an auto complete window will show listing the options of possible methods. Hovering/ browsing on a method from the option will show another window beside it that displays the method's description, which suddenly won't show anymore on my Android Studio. How can I turn this on back again?

[See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz90l.png)

Comment: You can view while mouse scroll click listener over a particular method. you can view where it is defined/declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out that what I was referring to is called **Quick Documentation View**.

---

**To open manually:**

> After the Code Completion Window shows, point to your chosen method then
>   press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

**Set to Autoshow:**

> Go to 
> *File > Settings > Editor > Code Completion > Show the
>   Documentation popup in `1000` ms.* 
> [See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcNIo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since Android Studio is based on IntelliJ I guess it will be similar to that.

In IntelliJ I need to press F1 when an autocomplete option is selected, to show me the docs for it.

If you don't want to press F1 everytime, you can press F1 twice, when an autocomplete option is selected, and it will open a doc view, which will update with each new selected element.